Implementing OIDC for simple delegated auth
I'd like to implement simple delegated authentication for my service with OpenID Connect, but I'm a bit confused what should happen after the client gets the credentials from the auth server.
I've got a prototype commandline client that opens the auth server's login page in the user's browser and has the callback handled on a local port, where it receives the access token and ID token.
But I'm unsure what then the service should be given/how it should verify what it's given.
Where should the service get the ID token from (the client or the auth sever?) which it needs to authenticate/determine which user the access token (given in the header of the client's requests) corresponds to?

The client receives the ID token, which informs the client how and when authentication occurred. The ID token stays in the client.
Your backend service / API has the resource server role and should only receive the access token. The API should not receive an ID token.
USER CLAIMS IN ACCESS TOKENS
The access token should identify the user in a way that is useful to the API. By default the access token may only contain a subject claim - a generated technical identifier.
Therefore it is common to configure the auth server to issue additional claims to identify the user. Personally I try to issue values like a customer_id or patient_id to the access token. In some cases an email might suffice.
So in your case it feels like you should do a little more work in your auth server to improve the claims in your access token.
